# shell output multiline text under bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Below is my toy program

```
xxxx@xxxx-Dell:~/Desktop$ foo=$'line1\nline2'
xxxx@xxxx-Dell:~/Desktop$ echo $foo
line1 line2
xxxx@jxxxx-Dell:~/Desktop$ echo "$foo"
line1
line2
```

I know quoting mechanism in shell command language. My expectation is two echo command would output same thing, as dollar sign is a meta-chracters anyway in plaintext and double qouting. So why is it different. Is it some nested qutation?

Comment: @DevNull  Thanks, I knew this way. My real issue is why echo  $foo and echo "$foo" behaves differently here

Comment: Ahh, after viewing the accepted answer, I see what you were looking for. Well, glad it worked itself out. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the quoted and unquoted versions may depend on your shell, but most likely is:

- quoted, `"$foo"` represents a single argument which is passed to the `echo` command, which prints it verbatim, followed by a newline.
- unquoted, `$foo` expands to a set of arguments separated by `$IFS`. If `$IFS` is unset, it defaults to whitespace, and if there is no field separator, you have just one field.

In the unquoted version, there's no reason to expect that the newline will be considered a part of the output, as it isn't even really part of the *input* to the `echo` command.  It simply separates arguments.

If you want to change this behaviour, you could change your `$IFS` setting, but I don't recommend it. Change IFS when you need to process fields, not to format your output.

For predictable output, follow the [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) recommendation, and don't use `echo` at all. Use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94) instead.

Comment: It is legit to use `IFS` to format the output as a field separator with array items (`"${array[*]}"`) or `"$*"`, but again that only takes effect inside double quotes.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks so much . I think you are right. I also tried  $'line1\tline2', which verified your explaination

Comment: FYI, I believe this is official doc.                                                                          "If a parameter expansion occurs inside double-quotes:
Pathname expansion shall not be performed on the results of the expansion.
Field splitting shall not be performed on the results of the expansion, with the exception of '@' ; see Special Parameters."